# Sitecore experience editor interface for scripts

Tags: sitecore7

we are moving from content editor to experience/page editor as our primary editor interface and one of the fields we deal with is a raw multiline field for dropping custom script into the pages by editors. Eg campaign management, google tag manager or similar

Currently if I render a SC:fieldrenderer via webforms the script tags are becoming part of the dom on render.

What is the best approach to tackle this type of interface requirement via experience editor in SC7 webforms - it looks like sitecore isnt outputting to an input tag in order to supress and contain the code and is instead outputting to a span which is then flowing into the dom.

Thanks for any direction

Comment: Maybe EditFrame is what you're looking for? https://www.google.com/search?q=sitecore+editframe

Comment: Hi that seems like a solution I will try - thanks for a quick reply!